# Prevent Conversion Of Text To Number? - Excel using PHP code

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying convert the DB data to excel format in PHP code, But while conversion it is changing number(45785695224589456584598752) to 4.57857E+25 format. How to avoid this?

Comment: Click on the cell... do you see the full number in the value bar?  Excel will show you values like this, but the underlying data is usually fine.

Comment: Does it still need to be a number data type in Excel?

Comment: Are you converting the data from mysql to a CSV, which is then opened in Excel? If so, use Data>Get External Data>From Text. In that dialog/wizard you can set the column with the REALLY big number to import as text instead of a number. Then your number won't get rounded and sentences to life as a scientific notation. Also... more information in your question, like how you are converting DB results to Excel would be supremely helpful.

Comment: Are you actually using the PHPExcel library? If so, show your code

Comment: I am using CSV format

Comment: Show your code or explain how you are writing the data from DB to Excel.

Comment: "I am using CSV format", "How to avoid this?"  The only two ways I know of using CSV and excel would be to change the column format on open of the excel document to text, or place a  ' (tic) before a number written out so it's treated as text, but that has it's own problems if you later need to do math with the number.  without using PHPexcel libraries or similar, this isn't easily doable.

Comment: Storing the CSV value as `="123456789012345678901234567890"` is another way with CSV, but doesn't lend itself well to being read by applications other than MS Excel

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem (conversion to floating point number which causes truncation and rounding errors.) I was using the fromArray() method to paste a whole query of data at a time, so using the setValueExplicit() approach suggested elsewhere was too much refactoring.

My solution was to force PHPExcel to not convert anything by providing a custom value binder class. This might be heavy handed for some people, so you can do something else based on this (if you need booleans or whatever): https://fossies.org/dox/moodle-latest-29/DefaultValueBinder_8php_source.html

```
class CustomPHPExcelValueBinder extends PHPExcel_Cell_DefaultValueBinder
{
    public function bindValue(PHPExcel_Cell $cell, $value = null)
    {
        // sanitize UTF-8 strings
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $value = PHPExcel_Shared_String::SanitizeUTF8($value);
        }

        // Set value explicit
        $cell->setValueExplicit($value, static::dataTypeForValue($value));

        // Done!
        return true;
    }

    public static function dataTypeForValue($pValue = null)
    {
        return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING;
    }

}
```

I use it like this:

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder(new CustomPHPExcelValueBinder());

$excelObj = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(__DIR__ . self::TEMPLATE_FILE);

$excelObj->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$excelObj->getActiveSheet()
    ->fromArray($rows, null, 'A2');
```